# Dynamically create Select boxes and assign values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Inside angular app.js I am dynamically placing multiple select box in a form with a unique id.  How can is get the values selected on those select boxes inside the controller.

Added a variable

```
$scope.sibling_type = {};
```

Javascript code to load the select box.

```
$scope.linkSiblingFinish = function(sibling){
   var str_siblingtype = "<div class='col-sm-2' style='margin-bottom:15px'>" +
     "<select ng-model='sibling_type[" + sibling.id + "]' class='form-control' id='sibling_type_"+sibling.id+"'>" +
       "<option class='ng-binding ng-scope' value='1'>Sister->Brother</option>" +
       "<option class='ng-binding ng-scope' value='2'>Brother->Sister</option>" +
       "<option class='ng-binding ng-scope' value='3'>Sister->Sister</option>" +
       "<option class='ng-binding ng-scope' value='4'>Brother->Brother</option>" +
     "</select></div>";

    document.getElementById('div_siblings').innerHTML = str_siblingtype;
}
```

The above script will be called on a button click from where the variable 'sibling' will be loaded with different 'id' every time.  Assume it has been called for 2 times with the id as '23' and '24'.  There will be 2 select boxes as 'sibling_type_23' and 'sibling_type_24'.

On submit button

```
$scope.saveSibling = function(data){
    dataFactory.httpRequest('index.php/students/sibling/'+$scope.form.id,'POST',{},$scope.form).then(function(data) {
    });
}
```

How do I bind/assign the option values so that when the form is submitted I can get the selected options on those select boxes inside Laravel controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different approach for this:

1. Create a new 'sibling_type' scope inside your controller.

   ```
   $scope.sibling_type = {};
   ```
2. Next, update the `ng-model` for all dynamic selects inside `linkSiblingFinish` like:

   ```
   "<select ng-model='sibling_type[" + sibling.id + "]' 
            class='form-control' id='sibling_type_"+sibling.id+"'>" +
   ```
3. Now, when the form is submitted you can get the selected options on those select boxes. like:

   ```
   var sibling_type_23 = $scope.sibling_type['23'];
   var sibling_type_24 = $scope.sibling_type['24'];
   ```

DEMO:

```js
const app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.siblings = [{id: 23,name: 'Sibling 23'},{id: 24,name: 'Sibling 24'}];
  $scope.sibling_type = {};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr ng-repeat="sibling in siblings">
        <td>{{sibling.name}}:</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="sibling_type[sibling.id]" placeholder='Type here..' /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <pre>{{sibling_type | json }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @palasH I tried the code and I am not able to get the values.  Enhanced the question a bit more.  Can you please support.  Thanks.